# Is $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{x \cos(x)^2}{1+x^3}$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

For the integral $$I= \int_1^{\infty}\frac{x \cos^2(x)}{1+x^3},$$ how do I test this for convergence or divergence?

I know that this an improper integral- however it cannot be solved so would need to use a comparison test for this.

Would the comparison test consist of: 
If $\cos(x)<1$ then we can use $1/(1+x^3)$ to show that it converges?

However... How can i compare the equation where there is an $x$ on the numerator of the original equation? Would I need to use something else to compare it with instead? Thanks.

Comment: Might be of some use, Mathematica gives an answer, but it looks terrible...

Comment: The first thing to test for, always, is absolute convergence.

Comment: @zhw. this is an improper integral, not a series

Comment: Why does that matter?

Comment: @zhw Absolute convergence is a topic in series, not in improper integration.

Comment: It's every bit a topic for improper integrals as it is for series.

Comment: @zhw how does absolute convergence have anything to do with improper integrals?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23484/discussion-between-salmonkiller-and-zhw).

Comment: OK, my last word on this (no need for chat): If $\int_0^\infty |f| < \infty,$ then the improper integral $\int_0^\infty f$ converges. This is basic, extremely well known, and plays the same role for improper integrals as does absolute convergence for series.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that $\cos^2(x) \leq 1$, therefore $$\frac{x \cos^2(x)}{1+x^3} \leq \frac{x}{1+x^3}.$$ You also know that $$\frac{1}{1+x^3} \leq \frac{1}{x^3}$$ for $x \in (1, \infty)$. Therefore $$\frac{x \cos^2(x)}{1+x^3} \leq \frac{x}{x^3} = \frac{1}{x^2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider comparing like this: $$\frac{x\cos^2 x}{1+x^3} \le \frac{x}{1+x^3} \le \frac{1}{x^2}$$

You can also do limit comparison to $\frac{x}{x^3}$.

Comment: not limit comparison, just comparison

Comment: Limit comparison with $\frac{x}{x^3}$ is also possible, I just didn't show it because it's pretty elementary.

Comment: It depends on the exact statement of limit comparison. If we compare with $\frac{1}{x^2}$ the limit does not exist. If we say compare with $\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$ the limit is $0$, and we are finished.